# Rspec setup issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4

there's something wrong with my rspec setup but I'm not sure what, all specs are being written as per normal but nothing is running as it should.

for example,

```
13) Event associations should have many :jobs
 Failure/Error: it { should have_many :jobs }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `has_many?' for #<Event:0x007ffdb0140978>
 # ./spec/models/event_spec.rb:14:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'


  8) Event validations 
 Failure/Error: it { should validate_presence_of :start_date }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `validate_presence_of' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Event_2::Validations:0x007ffdb02a1268>
 # ./spec/models/event_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

[Gist for Gemfile](https://gist.github.com/sherwyngoh/9f0751ceb16c40bd738d)

[Pastie for Spec Helper](http://pastie.org/8960734)

Am doing TDD so can't really get started till this is  up and running, please provide assistance someone!

EDIT

Event.rb

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
 validates_presence_of :start_date, :end_date, :description, :title

 has_many :jobs
 has_many :applications, through: :jobs
 has_many :users, through: :applications
 has_many :companies, through: :jobs
end

require 'spec_helper'

describe Event do
  context "validations" do
  it { should validate_presence_of :title }
  it { should validate_presence_of :description }
  it { should validate_presence_of :start_date }
  it { should validate_presence_of :end_date }
  end

context "associations" do
 it { should have_many :companies }

 it { should have_many :jobs }
 it { should have_many(:applications).through(:jobs) }
 it { should have_many(:users).through(:applications) }
end

context "custom methods" do

end
end
```

Comment: It would be much more helpful if you showed the code that's causing the error. i.e. event_spec.rb

Comment: @Dty added! have a look, thanks

Comment: Are you using Shoulda? If so, include this gem for the required matchers: https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `shoulda-matchers` in the `test` group.

```
group :test do
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
end
```